# backbonejs - accessing collection in view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

backbonejs and oop js newbie here. i am trying to bind my collection to a view, when i go to my console, i only get this 
**this is a collection: [object Object]**

is there something am i missing here?

```
  var root = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

  var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({});

  var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Post,
    url: root + "/posts",
    parse: function(response) {
      return response;
    }
  });
  var posts = new Posts();
  posts.fetch();

  // View wrapper to render view child items
  var PostsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    collection: new Posts(),
    initialize: function() {
      console.log('this is a collection: ' + this.collection);
    },
    render: function() {
      // STEPS:
      // filter through all items in a collection
      // for each item, create a new PostView
      // append to root element, ex. ul
    }
  });
  var postsview = new PostsView();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `'this is a collection: ' + this.collection` you're forcing the collection to be a string, and javascript sees an object and turns it into your **[object Object]**.

The correct way to show a collection as a string is to just its `.toJSON()` function and do `console.log('this is a collection: ' + JSON.stringify(this.collection.toJSON()));` but since most devtools are capable of properly showing an object natively you're better off using

```
console.log('this is a collection: ', this.collection);
```

That should give you a nice interactive representation of the collection in your console, at least on Chrome.

Comment: i tried both `console.log('this is a collection: ' + JSON.stringify(this.collection.toJSON()));` and `console.log('this is a collection: ' + this.collection.toJSON());` and it spits out `[]`

i am trying to access [object Object] to were i can view what it contains, like its properties and methods

Comment: @ReinaLynBen Then you're dealing with an empty collection. Keep in mind that `.fetch` is async, and in your view's initialize try `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', function() { console.log(this.collection) })`